# I am trying to run a query based on the results from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, stored-procedures, distinct, execute

First, here is the code for sp_GetWorkQByUserName:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetWorkQByUserName]
    ( @UserName varchar(50),
      @StartDate datetime,
      @EndDate datetime )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT DISTINCT SpotId FROM tblSpotCount WHERE StoreNum = EXECUTE sp_GetUserLocationCodes(@UserName)
        ORDER BY SpotDt ASC 
    END
```

I know my `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is wrong, but I wrote it like that to help show what I'm trying to do. I want to run this stored procedure based on the results from the `sp_GetUserLocationCodes` with a  parameter of `@UserName`.

From what I can tell, my problem lies in how I'm calling `sp_GetUserLocationCodes`.

Question: how can I run a `SELECT DISTINCT` query on `tblSpotCount.SpotId` based on the results from the `sp_GetUserLocationCodes` stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a stored procedure directly in a query. You can, however, insert the results of a stored procedure into a temporary table and use that in your query:

```
CREATE TABLE #storeLocations
(
    -- appropriate column names and data types go here
)

INSERT INTO #storeLocations (put column list here)
EXECUTE sp_GetUserLocationCodes(@UserName)

SELECT DISTINCT SpotId
FROM tblSpotCount
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #storeLocations
              WHERE #storeLocations.StoreNum = tblSpotCount.StoreNum)
ORDER BY SpotDt ASC

DROP TABLE #storeLocations
```